# Kubernetes: How to allow two pods running in same/different namespace communicate irrespective of the protocol using a servicename?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service, kubernetes-networkpolicy

Allow two pods (say pod A and B) running in same/different namespace communicate irrespective of the protocol(say http,https,akka.tcp) along with a valid Network policy applied.

***Solutions tried:***

1. Tried applying network policy to both the pods and also used the service name: “my-svc.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local” to make pod B
   communicate to pod A which is running the service “my-svc” but both
   failed to communicate.
2. Also tried adding the IP address and host mapping of pod A in pod B while it’s deployment, then pod B was able to communicate to pod A
   but inverse communication is failing.

Kindly suggest me a way to fix this.

Answer (score 30):

By default, pods can communicate with each other by their IP address, regardless of the namespace they're in.

You can see the IP address of each pod with:

```
kubectl get pods -o wide --all-namespaces
```

However, the normal way to communicate within a cluster is through Service resources.

A Service also has an IP address and additionally a DNS name. A Service is backed by a set of pods. The Service forwards requests to itself to one of the backing pods.

The fully qualified DNS name of a Service is:

```
<service-name>.<service-namespace>.svc.cluster.local
```

This can be resolved to the IP address of the Service from anywhere in the cluster (regardless of namespace).

For example, if you have:

- Namespace `ns-a`: Service `svc-a` → set of pods A
- Namespace `ns-b`: Service `svc-b` → set of pods B

Then a pod of set A can reach a pod of set B by making a request to:

```
svc-b.ns-b.svc.cluster.local
```

Comment: yes as mentioned in my 1st attempted solution, used similar service name [ _svc-a.ns-a.svc.cluster.local_ ] to communicate from Pod B to Pod A, but it failed.

Comment: Did you add any NetworkPolicies or do any other settings? It should work by default in a fresh cluster.

Answer (score 7):

You can put the Pods behind [Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) and use [Service DNS](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) for communication. Calls to `service-name` allow Pods in the same namespace to communicate. Calls to `service-name.namespace` allow Pods in different namespaces to communicate.

Comment: Can you share an example?

Comment: here is the example:    $curl http://{service_name}.{namespace_name}:{port_number}

Comment: @VadimSluzky I am not able to curl with the format you have given, but I am able to do it with pod ip  :(

Comment: @DarshanaPatel make sure you have labels in your service file  here is the example   labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name

Comment: which is the most performant?

Answer (score 0):

When trying to reach a service using it’s short name, a pod will look it up only in it’s own namespace, not across all namespaces in the cluster. So to answer your question: each Pod A will only talk to it’s “local” Pod B.

For a Pod A in one namespace to reach a Pod B in another namespace, you will need to use the fqdn of the service in ns2 which would be something like: ..svc.cluster.local.